# acts-as-taggable-on tag owner bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I have code such as:

```
Parent Class
->acts_as tagger

Child Class
->acts_as_taggable
```

If I print 'child.tag_list' I get the correct result e.g. 'A'. If I print 'parent.owned_tags' I get:

```
#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 7, name: "A">
```

Any ideas why the format for the parents owned tags appears this way?

Answer (score 0):

I've only been using acts-as-taggable-on for a week, but here's my two cents...

I think it's because typically when you get and set tags on a taggable object, it's easiest to do it with a string. When we want to know the tags we own, we want the actual objects, through the taggings, in a collection so we can do what we want. In your case we'd map that array with something like `parent.owned_tags.map{|tag| tag.name}.join(', ')` I think.

Does that make sense? It'd be nice to add a method so we could do `parent.owned_tag_list`. Maybe that exists already for outputting a string?!